# Rollup + Typescript + ESLint wrong warning

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, rollupjs

I created a project using Rollup which use Typescript and ESLint with the typescript-eslint plugin and it seems that ESLint is executed on compiled code.

Here is my Rollup config :

```
export default commandLineArgs => {
  const serving = commandLineArgs.configServe === true;

  return {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'bot',
      sourcemap: !isProduction
    },
    plugins: [
      eslint({ include: ['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.ts'] }),
      nodeResolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ sourceMap: !isProduction, inlineSources: !isProduction }),
      replace({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(isProduction ? 'production' : 'development')
      }),
      scss({
        includePaths: ['node_modules/'],
        outputStyle: isProduction ? 'compressed' : 'expanded'
      }),
      html({ include: 'src/**/*.html' }), // to allow import of html files (for templating)
      image(), // to allow import of image files
      isProduction && terser(),
      isProduction && filesize(),
      serving && serve({
        open: true,
        openPage: '/index.html',
        contentBase: ['demo', 'dist'],
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my main.ts :

```
import './styles/app.scss';

import ChatUI from './ui';
import Chat from './chat';

export default async function init(target: HTMLDivElement): Promise<Chat> {
  const ui = new ChatUI(target);
  const chat = new Chat(ui);

  return chat;
}
```

And this is what ESLint logs :

```
.../src/main.ts
4:16  warning  Missing return type on function    @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
4:36  warning  Argument 'target' should be typed  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
```

As you can see, both line numbers and errors are wrong, as if it use the generated js file rather than the ts source. What is the problem here ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the "official" version, `@rollup/plugin-eslint`, is outdated, and uses an old version of eslint. There are two available alternatives that are more current: [`@rbnlffl/rollup-plugin-eslint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rbnlffl/rollup-plugin-eslint) and [`rollup-plugin-eslint2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-eslint2). The former did the trick for me; I haven't tried the latter.

Comment: Currently `@rollup/plugin-eslint` is the most recently updated ‍♂️ 